# Every time making a live Ubuntu USB makes the USB not usable anymore

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I usually create a live USB using Startup disk creator. I'm currently working on Ubuntu 18.04.

Every time I make a live Ubuntu USB stick, it works, and I can use it as a live USB stick. But every time when I try to use it as a normal USB or try to format it, it doesn't work most of the time. Just some few times it works after formatting. Most of the time the problem is noticed when I try to use the USB on Windows. In these cases, Windows don't recognize the USB stick and demands formatting the USB stick before using it.

The problem is usually is related to partition table.

Is there some way I can avoid this repeated problem and try using a USB as one-use-only?

Answer (score 1):

You can wipe the first mibibyte with zeros and after that create a new partition table with the partitions you want.

This can be done in two steps with `mkusb` and after that `gparted`, or if you wish to have a standard USB pendrive with an MSDOS partition table and a partition with the FAT32 file system in one single step with `mkusb`.

See these links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Postrequisites_-_restore_the_USB_stick)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)